# Problems running a 32-bit Delphi app on a 64-bit Windows platform

Tags: delphi, winapi, printing, compatibility, win64

I have a Windows 32 bit app written in Delphi that is giving problems when running under Windows Server 2008 64-bit.

Details are sketchy ("having all kinds of printing issues" was the best report I could get so far) and the app behaves fine on all the Win64 platforms I have access to, but aside from that, I would have thought that an app compiled for a Win32 target should run pretty much out of the box on Win64.

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: My 32 bit Delphi apps run just fine under Server 2008 64bit, SBS 2008 64bit, Win 7 64bit, Win Vista 64 bit and Win XP 64 bit. Maybe the use of Server 2008 is just a coincidence and the problem is elsewhere!

Comment: Thanks Cosmin.  When I can extract some coherent details from the client I will report back.

Comment: I've had problems printing from a 32 bit app on 64 bit servers running terminal services. It seems once one client has printed others can't print until the splwow64.exe process exits or is killed.

Comment: SO isn't a site for *I'm having this vague problem. I don't have any details or code. Can you throw out a bunch of ideas on what might be the cause or how I might fix it, in the hopes that one of them turns out to be right?* questions.

Comment: @KenWhite: it probably was in 2010 though 

Comment: @halfer: Hmm... Maybe.:-)

Answer (score 2):

I could be a buggy printer driver.

On win32 som HP drivers need to have en special floating point flag.
See: http://rave-notes.blogspot.com/2008/01/rave-reports-and-problems-with-hp.html

Comment: Thanks for that. The post mentions the property RpDev.SkipAbortProc.  I can't find hide nor hair of that property in my Rave documentation or on the web (apart from in that post).

Comment: I have seen an "floating point overflow" error using reportbuilder.
If i remember correctly, i was during selection of printer.
It was also described in Digital Metaphors ReportBuilder support.
See http://delphigroups.info/2/4/973047.html Last response (by Nard Moseley)

Answer (score 0):

I Have 3 Computers connected via wifi to an Hp Laserjet pro M14-M17.

Win 11 Delphi 11 32 bit delphi
Win 10 Delphi 10 32 bit delphi

Email documents and  word all print perfectly.

Any program made with delphi or lazerus will only print if the printer is connected directly to the computer with a USB cable.

The solution I came up with was to use the oldest computer as a print server. Directly connecting the printer via usb.

Make additions to the firewall on all three computers to allow file and printer sharing through.

Enable advanced file and printer sharing on all the computers.

Set the new printer to be the default. Give it a sensible share name .Ie Closet1HplaserJetM14-M17

It may take several tweaks to modify firewall settings to stick.

In conclusion I have been told that low cost printers do the print rendering in the Pc have this problem.

A true network printer that be reached across a large area won't have have this problem.